# Gmail won't complete contact to "To" field

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

Ok, I got a weird issue with a specific gmail account. Whenever I click on a contact from the suggestions list in gmail the mail address won't get inserted into the "To" field. I've tried the same account on a different PC and the issue went away but when using that particular account on my main computer the issue just won't go away. Also tried different browsers which didn't work, cleaning chrome's cache didn't work, different windows user account didn't work and ofc other accounts on that pc did work. Any ideas?